# Заставить Angular увидеть изменение input

Tags: javascript, angular

Есть чужой сайт, по сообщению из консоли на нем используется Angular. На данном сайте мне нужно изменить `input`, чтобы он увидел это. То есть, если написать руками что-то в `input`, кнопка становится активной, но если через JS - нет.
Через JS изменял такими способами:

```js
document.querySelector('input').setAttribute('value', '1');
```

```js
document.querySelector('input').value = '1';
```

Добавлю, я это выполняю из консоли код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я долго искал решение данного вопроса до создания вопроса, но все же смог найти (почему-то этот вариант не работал раньше).

```js
document.querySelector('input').dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
```