# Программно ввести текст и отправить форму

Tags: javascript, консоль, input, click

Есть сайт: https://msk.tele2.ru/lk, при переходе открывается форма, мне нужно ввести номер в поле и нажать далее, в консоли я написал нечто подобное, но все равно не выходит нажать, буду рад если поможете разобраться

```js
document.getElementById("keycloakAuth.phone").value = "+7 951 544-13-15";
document.getElementsByClassName("keycloak-login-form__button btn btn-black")[0].click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('keycloakAuth.phone').value = '+7 951 000-00-00';
document.getElementById('keycloakAuth.phone').dispatchEvent(new Event('blur'));
document.querySelector('.keycloak-login-form__button').click();
```

Comment: А вот ваш вариант сработал, спасибо

Comment: а можете помочь еще отправить код, которые возникает в последствии? я просто не много не понимаю в событиях которые нужны и как их отрабатывать т.к. Js касаюсь достаточно редко, но понимаю что для продолжения многих работ он мне пригодится, если не сложно могли бы вы поделиться ссылочкой где это можно разобрать или могли бы вы мне сами не много рассказать про это, конкретнее какие события нужны и как и выполнять?

Answer (score 0):

Я как-то сталкивался с данной проблемой и создавал тему: [тема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1275639/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-angular-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-input). В ней я решил данную проблему. И решение работает и в вашем случае:

```js
document.getElementById("keycloakAuth.phone").value = "+7 951 544-13-15";
document.getElementById("keycloakAuth.phone").dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }));
document.getElementsByClassName("keycloak-login-form__button btn btn-black")[0].click();
```

Вторая строчка кода сообщает, что произошло событие "input" у поля, дабы сработал обработчик на сайте.

Comment: к сожалению не работает, если обновить страницу, никуда не клацать, ввести консоль, то не работает, будет работать если только активировать input

Answer (score 0):

Не пойму как действовать дальше, там появляется 6 полей, они реагируют только на ввод текста или на ctrl + v, пытался поступить так:

```
document.getElementById("codeSymbolField1_0").value = 8;
document.getElementById("codeSymbolField1_1").value = 5;
document.getElementById("codeSymbolField1_2").value = 0;
document.getElementById("codeSymbolField1_3").value = 4;
document.getElementById("codeSymbolField1_4").value = 7;
document.getElementById("codeSymbolField1_5").value = 6;
document.getElementById("codeSymbolField1_5").dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {key : "v", ctrlKey: true} ));
```

Но результатов особо не дало, с событиями более менее пытаюсь разбираться, но до конца пока логику не пойму